# Unable to delete folders from Mac archive on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, windows-10, filesystems, ntfs

I extracted a zip file, but found that I cannot delete the extracted folders afterwards. Including the actual file folder and the `__MACOSX` folder.

If I shift-delete these files, nothing happens. If I try to delete them normally, I get an error message that says

> "Could not find this item. This is no longer located in C:..."

My friend is on MacOS, not sure which version, while I'm running Windows 10 on NTFS.

How can I force delete these folders?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself:

1. Open a command prompt from the lowest-level child directory
2. Enter "dir /x" to see the content
3. Manually delete the files/folders using the 8.3 file names
4. Repeat as necessary until the parent directory can be deleted as well

Answer (score 0):

First make sure all directories and folders are no longer opened that might be associated with what you are looking to delete.  If you have a window open or a terminal screen open that is associated with the files you wish to delete, it will not let you delete it because those items might have a lock on the items you wish to delete.  Now open a terminal window and go to the folder that contains what you wish to delete.  Now use the following command to delete the folder you want to remove.  'chmod 775 MyDirectory' and then 'rm -rf MyDirectory' The first command ensures that you have rights to the directory.  The second command will force your directory to be deleted and all of its contents to be deleted.  Of course MyDirectory is the directory you are looking to delete in this example.  This is assuming two things.  You have an administrator account and/or have the ability to change the rights on a folder.  And all locks on this directory are removed.  It may help to reboot in order to ensure nothing has a lock on the directory first before starting this process.

Hope this helps

Comment: chmod & rm on Windows?

Comment: Well you COULD do it using Cygwin however I understand that might not be something you want to do.  I've often used Cygwin to by-pass windows SLOW process of deleting files.  I'd then suggest right clicking on the folder and making sure it isn't READ ONLY.  It will then ask you if you want to apply the changes to to everything inside of it.  Answer YES.

Answer (score 0):

i found a simple way to do it. if you have WinZip or WinRar just make that folder into zip or rar, but make sure that you set the folder to be automatically deleted after archiving. after that just delete the compressed folder.